# Do Repair spells work on constructs that can have negative HP?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, healing, hit-points

The **Clockwork Automaton** template makes a creature a construct with a soul.
The [Inorganic Functioning](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/clockwork-automaton-cr-0#TOC-Inorganic-Functioning-Ex-) extraordinary ability says "if the creature reaches 0 HP or below, the automaton will case [sic] functioning and be treated as unconscious." (I think 'case' should be 'cease'.)

*Rapid Repair* says "It has no effect on a construct that has been brought to 0 hit points or destroyed."

Does Rapid Repair work on a construct with less than 0 hit points? 
Is this a loophole or just a overlooked posibility?

Is the additional cost for negative hit points described in [Inorganic Functioning](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/clockwork-automaton-cr-0#TOC-Inorganic-Functioning-Ex-) only added when using Craft to repair or also when using a repair spell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably a matter of two different things that operate in unusual ways not accounting for one another.

Usually, when a construct is reduced below 0 HP, it is destroyed. The limitation on *rapid repair* covers this case, and doesn’t work.

But Clockwork Automaton has the creature become Unconscious, rather than destroyed, when below 0 HP. The whole **point** of the ability is so that they can be repaired more easily than typical resurrections; it explicitly says they “can be restored by use of the *make whole* spell [...] or other repair spells for constructs.” That said, I note that *make whole* does not use the same line as *rapid repair* about not working for constructs that are destroyed or at 0 HP.

Ultimately, the fact that *rapid repair* does not work for constructs at 0 HP (when a construct is *normally* inert but not destroyed) implies to me that it *should not* work for Clockwork Automatons below 0 HP. RAW, however, this unusual exception to the typical construct rules is not explicitly covered by *rapid repair*.

But this is a specific limitation of *rapid repair*; other spells that lack the line about not working on constructs with 0 HP, I would allow to work, per Inorganic Functioning’s statement that Clockwork Automatons “can be restored by [...] other repair spells for constructs.”

Regarding extra costs, that much, at least, is clear: “Regardless of the method used,” repairing a Clockwork Automaton with 0 or less HP is going to be expensive. Even if the method used would usually be free.

Comment: what about the additional cost, does it count for _make whole_?

Comment: @shaggy1987 Added to the answer; yes, yes it does.